# How do I transfer a collect user input in a COBOL program and store in an SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, cobol

Please how can i create a COBOL program with embedded SQL that accepts user input and uses SQL to INSERT into a table. I know how to insert using SQL, but i dont know how to transfer the COBOL ACCEPT input to the SQL table

```
        EXEC SQL DECLARE A05544 TABLE                     
        ( CUST_ID                        CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
          PROD                           CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
          PRIC                           CHAR(6) NOT NULL 
        ) END-EXEC.
    01  DCLA05544.                       
        10 CUST_ID              PIC X(6).
        10 PROD                 PIC X(6).
        10 PRIC                 PIC X(6).
```

Above is the embedded SQL table declaration for the table I want to insert into

```
    WELCOME.
        DISPLAY 'INPUT CUSTOMER ID'
```

This is how the program starts

Ive tried to insert this way

```
EXEC SQL            
    INSERT INTO A05544
    (CUST_ID)         
    VALUES(CID_ADD)   
END-EXEC
```

but I get the error DSNHANAL LINE 225 COL 14  STATEMENT REFERENCES COLUMN 'A05544''CID_ADD', WHICH IS NOT DECLARED IN THE SPECIFIED TABLE(S)

Comment: @BruceMartin i have added the sql i tried

Comment: [Embedded] refers to embedded systems, which involves areas such as microcontroller/DSP firmware programming, real-time systems, electronic interfaces, hardware drivers, serial bus communication etc. ....please remove this tag from the question.

Comment: @hiddenleaf
Please recheck the answer and have a look at stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers - please either comment about unclear parts or vote + accept.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reference to CID_ADD anywhere in the COBOL part, is it? It *looks* like this is the variable you've `ACCEPT`ed beforehand, in this case use `:` to tell the precompiler about your intentions:

```
EXEC SQL            
    INSERT INTO A05544
    (CUST_ID)         
    VALUES(:CID_ADD)   
END-EXEC
```

Comment: Yes I have previously ACCEPT ed CID_ADD. But are you saying i shouldn't define it in the WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. when using the code you provided?

Comment: @hiddenleaf
No, you should define COBOL variables as COBOL variables, but when you reference them in `EXEC SQL` prefix them with a colon `:`.